# Node Server, is a database necessary for basic authentication if using oauth?

Tags: node.js, authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, passport.js

I'm learning Node, doing authentication stuff at the moment with passport.
Say my server has 2 pages, a public home page with various login options, then a super-secret page(and perhaps more) that is only accessible after authenticating.

If I'm only going to be using 3rd party strategies, is there any reason to have a database?
I know that you'd obviously need one for local user's id and pass, but if the server exclusively relies on 3rd party authentication, would session persistence be enough things to work? Or are there still various things that you would need to save for some reason (apart from logging) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you do without a database, sure... but in this case what is the point in authenticating at all? All you would be proving is that the user has a Google account which anyone can set up for free in a matter of minutes.

If your content is super secret then chances are you want to have a database of users (email addresses and the like) that have permission to see the content. By authenticating through OAuth you will be given an access token that will allow you to fetch the authenticated users email address. This can then be looked up against your user table to see if the user is registered and if your app enforces it, check whether the user has access to the page requested.

OAuth is proving that this person is the owner of the Google/Facebook/Twitter/Github Account. You can use this knowledge to sign someone in against a database of "local accounts" based on email used at sign up, assuming you validate the email on sign up locally.

Comment: Does that mean no one relies on 3rd party to provide the needed info each and every time? Instead, they get it once, save it locally and I guess update that info as needed?

Comment: Not quite. On sign up if you supported Google OAuth you would let someone sign in with their Google account. That person would be redirected to Google and Grant your application permission to get profile information like name and email address. Google would respond with an ID Token that contains name, email whether the email is valid etc. You would then authenticate this email against your user database. If the user existed you can go ahead and start a session, otherwise you would direct the user through your new user sign up process, being able to pee populate steps thanks to the info in the

Comment: one use-case would be for internal applications, which don't have need to users.  You could require that a user have an google account for a given domain name (EG: @myCompany.com)